# Faster alternative to populate data in list from second list with other properties

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, foreach

I've searched for a solution on SO but I couldn't find it, so I've made this new question.

I have 2 list of two different classes.

First class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int C1Property1 {get;set;}
    public int C1Property2 {get;set;}
    public int C1Property3 {get;set;}
}
```

And second class:

```
public class Class2
{
    public int C2Property1 {get;set;}
    public int C2Property2 {get;set;}
    public int C2Property3 {get;set;}
}
```

And I have two list of those classes:

```
List<Class1> Class1List = new List<Class1>();
List<Class2> Class2List = new List<Class2>();
```

Now comes the hard part for me: Two of those properties in both classes have the same value, but with a different name: i.e. `C1Property1 = C2Property1` and `C1Property2 = C2Property2`. The list `Class1List` has the property `C1Property1` which is empty, and I need to populate it using the property from `Class2List`. I do this by using the following code:

```
foreach(var element1 in Class1List)
{
     foreach(var element2 in Class2List)
     {
         if(element2.C2Property2 == element1.C1Property2)
         {
             element1.C1Property1 = element2.C2Property1;
         }
     }
}
```

This solution works how I intent it, but is very ugly and I have 2 foreach-loops which can be slow (list can contain over 10 000 elements). In the example classes I wrote only 3 properties to show how it works, but originally it has ~20 properties each, and only 2 of them are the same. Can I do this faster and more efficient? Some LinQ perhaps? I can't show more code, sorry. I hope that you will understand what I'm asking.
I need to take only one property from `Class2List` and place it on `Class1List` only when one of parameters in list are same.

In my second attempt i use something like that :

```
foreach (var element1 in Class1List)
{
    foreach (var element2 in Class2List.Where(element2 => element2.C2Property2 == element1.C1Property2 ))
    {
        element2.C2Property2 = element1.C1Property2;
        break;
    }
}
```

This should be faster but still look ugly

Comment: I've edited your post so it's easier to read. As for your problem, I'm not sure how to make it more efficient. Even if you do use Linq to make it a one-liner, it will still do the foreach-loops behind the scenes if I'm not mistaken. But there are a lot of people here on SO with more knowledge than me, so perhaps someone else has a suggestion that works. @NSNoob That question combines two lists of different classes into one, while OP wants to set the property of one object-value in list1 to another object-value in list2 (and also compare two other properties for equality).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oh okay. thanks for explaining that kevin

Comment: Yea sorry for English I know that was hard to understand :)

Comment: Why don't you break after setting the property? Is it possible (and wanted) that there are more elements in Class2List that have an equal property and should change element1`s property?

Comment: Isn't the fastest solution to 1. sorting both lists, 2. Use a single `while` with `index1` and `index2` where you only increase the index which looses `list1.PropertyA.CompareTo(list2.Property2)`. Should give you a lot less iterations. Especially if the lists are similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here I have three options:

#### Using LINQ

```
Class1List.ForEach(element1 =>
{
    Class2 element2 = Class2List.FirstOrDefault(e2 => e2.C2Property2 == element1.C1Property2);
    if (element2 != null) element1.C1Property1 = element2.C2Property1;
});
```

This took my machine 4.58s for 20000 elements in each list. And though the code looks (to me) a little better, this is effectivly the same as your code.

#### Using a dictionary

Using a dictionary to access the `Class2` elements via a hash is really effective:

```
Dictionary<int, Class2> dictionary =                Class2List.GroupBy(e2 => e2.C2Property2, e2 => e2).Select(elements => elements.First()).ToDictionary(e2 => e2.C2Property2, e2 => e2);

Class1List.ForEach(element1 =>
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(element1.C1Property2))
        element1.C1Property1 = dictionary[element1.C1Property2].C2Property1;
});
```

This took my machine 0.00878s for 20000 elements in each list.

#### Parallel

If your data gets really really big, you might consider to use [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dictionary<int, Class2> dictionary =
            Class2List.GroupBy(e2 => e2.C2Property2, e2 => e2).Select(elements => elements.First()).ToDictionary(e2 => e2.C2Property2, e2 => e2);

Parallel.ForEach(Class1List, element1 =>
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(element1.C1Property2))
        element1.C1Property1 = dictionary[element1.C1Property2].C2Property1;
});
```

But with only 20000 elements in each list this took my machine even longer (0.0197s) than the non-parallel version.

Comment: Dictionary option look bet in my opinion :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was a pretty interesting thing to figure out, but I think something like this might work:

```
Class1List.ForEach(c1 =>
    c1.C1Property1 = Class2List.Where(c2 => c2.C2Property2 == c1.C1Property2)
                               .Select(r => r.C2Property1)
                               .FirstOrDefault());
```

Here is a test class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO_Test
{
    public class ObjectA
    {
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
        public int? Property2 { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("({0}, {1})", Property1, Property2);
        }
    }

    public class ObjectB
    {
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
        public int? Property2 { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("({0}, {1})", Property1, Property2);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var listA = new List<ObjectA>
            { 
                new ObjectA { Property1 = 5,  Property2 = null }, 
                new ObjectA { Property1 = 16, Property2 = null }, 
                new ObjectA { Property1 = 9,  Property2 = null }, 
                new ObjectA { Property1 = 38, Property2 = null } 
            };
            var listB = new List<ObjectB>
            { 
                new ObjectB { Property1 = 5, Property2 = 1 }, 
                new ObjectB { Property1 = 9, Property2 = 2 }, 
                new ObjectB { Property1 = 16, Property2 = 3 } 
            };

            Console.WriteLine("BEFORE");
            Console.WriteLine("ListA: {0}", String.Join(", ", listA));
            Console.WriteLine("ListB: {0}", String.Join(", ", listB));

            listA.ForEach(a =>
                a.Property2 = listB.Where(b => b.Property1 == a.Property1)
                                   .Select(r => r.Property2)
                                   .FirstOrDefault());

            Console.WriteLine("AFTER");
            Console.WriteLine("ListA: {0}", String.Join(", ", listA));
            Console.WriteLine("ListB: {0}", String.Join(", ", listB));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BEFORE
ListA: (5, ), (16, ), (9, ), (38, )
ListB: (5, 1), (9, 2), (16, 3)
AFTER
ListA: (5, 1), (16, 3), (9, 2), (38, )
ListB: (5, 1), (9, 2), (16, 3)
```